# Conditionally run Azure DevOps task based on string from previous task log

Tags: azure-devops, jmeter

I have a CI pipeline which runs a couple of JMeter tests and some Powershell scripts.

If a JMeter test fails, it still reports as successful in DevOps.

However, the log will have "Err:" followed by how many calls in the test failed.

How can I only run the following task (Write Threadreferences) if the "Run Outbound Email JMeter Test" task has finished and does NOT contain "Err:" in the log?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jmeter test was returning an `Object[]` inside the Powershell script, so the trick was to iterate through the array and see if there were any errors, if there were, throw an Exception.
This makes the step fail in the pipeline and therefore the subsequent steps don't execute.

```
$logs = jmeter -n -t $TestFilePath 
$successLogFound = $false
foreach($log in $logs)
{
    if($log.Contains("Err:     0"))
    {
        $successLogFound = $true
        break;
    }
}
if(!$successLogFound)
{
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    Write-Error "Test failed."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the better option would be failing the whole "Run Outbound Email JMeter Test" task so if there are failures it would return [non-zero exit status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) so the pipeline would "catch" it

For example you can run your test using [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin), the simple *pom.xml* would be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Generate JMeter configuration -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>configuration</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>configure</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>results</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And output:

[image]

Alternatively you can use [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) automation framework which has [Pass/Fail criteria subsystem](https://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/)

Example configuration:

```
execution:
- scenario: simple

scenarios:
  simple:
    script: test.jmx

reporting:
- module: passfail
  criteria:
  - succ<100%, continue as failed
```

and output:

[image]