# Installing JMeter for tests in Azure DevOps pipeline job

Tags: jmeter, azure-pipelines

I will link this stack overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66380935/9016391)
where you could see what I am interesting in. I have a JMeter tests than i need to run in Azure DevOps pipeline. I've done something that looks like that ( tests are run in pipeline as I expected ) but was told that I haven't made it good, was not following best practices. I've placed JMeter install files into our Repo for testing ( inside that repo are our .jmx files as well ).

So basically I created PowerShell script that is calling JMeter .exe and .jmx file, and that PowerShell is later called in YAML file.

I would like to install JMeter every time the pipeline is run, instead having installation in repo, and to do so i would like it to do through pipeline task/step.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Installing" JMeter in Powershell it's a matter of 2 commands:

1. `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.5.zip -OutFile jmeter.zip`
2. `Expand-Archive -Path 'jmeter.zip'`

More information:

- [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.2)
- [Expand-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-7.2)
- [JMeter Installation: How to Get Started](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation)